# +[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil (Cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having this issue with cocos2d. Hopefully someone else has seen this before. The error message (in the title):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation
>   invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be
>   nil

keeps coming up when I'm trying to draw a scene. To get to it, you click a button on the main menu and it brings you directly to it. I've stepped into it and it crashes on the line where I'm trying to add some buttons:

```
CCMenuItem *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage 
  itemFromNormalImage:@"menubtn-normal.png" 
  selectedImage:@"menubtn-pressed.png" 
  target:self     
  selector:@selector(displayMatchMaker:)];
```

When I use the method where "target: self selector:@selector(displayMatchMaker:)]" is not there, it works fine and draws the button. The displayMatchMaker: method DOES exist, in this same implementation. I'm beginning to lose my mind here! Hopefully someone can help me!

Here's the method implementation:

```
- (void)displayMatchMaker:(id)sender{
...
}
```

Comment: Did you declare the method header in the `.h` file?

Comment: Yes, the .h file has :  - (void)displayMatchMaker:(id)sender;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the code was in the wrong spot. It was crashing because it technically couldn't see the method, even though it was in the same implementation. Once I moved the code over to a new location, it worked fine.

Comment: That doesn't explain much... Do you know why exactly it started working again?

Comment: How did you fix it? I'm having the same problem and this answer doesn't help at all!

Comment: I had it broken into class and instance methods. It the wrong one (ie. It was an instance method, and needed to be a class method).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the selector should be without colon:

`@selector(displayMatchMaker)`

> `-(void) displayMatchMaker { }`

Comment: No, that's not right. All IBActions should take one argument: the sender.

Comment: I have a bunch of other methods that have the colon, all of which work. I don't understand what I'm doing differently, since there is nothing different. I have literally copy and pasted the ones that work and changed a few names.

Comment: Stepping inside CCMenuItem, there's only one line adding an argument to the NSInvocation instance:
   [invocation_ setArgument:&self atIndex:2];
This could indicate that your menuItem1 may be deallocated.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that it's deallocated, since that's where it's being allocated. It's crashing on the line that CREATES the element.